# Get the sum of the values in the map

Tags: java, java-stream

I have to get the sum of the values in the map after applying an operation on each value.

I have done like this:

```
   Map<Employee, Integer> employeeBudget = committedHoursPerDay.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, o -> o.getKey().getHourlyWage() * o.getValue()));

    //Get the total cost for all the employee
    int manpowerBudget = employeeBudget.values()
            .stream()
            .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
            .sum();
```

This solution works. I think there is a better way to solve this but I ca not figure it out.

Comment: Looks quite elegant to me already. Do you reuse `employeeBudget` after this? If not, you could stream from `committedHoursPerDay` directly down to the sum.

Comment: would `int manpowerBudget = committedHoursPerDay.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .mapToInt(o -> o.getKey().getHourlyWage() * o.getValue())
        .sum();` work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, I think you could do that with only one stream:

```
int manpowerBudget = committedHoursPerDay.entrySet().stream()
                .mapToInt(kv-> kv.getKey().getHourlyWage() * kv.getValue())
                .sum();
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you do not need to collect it into a `Map` just to sum values. Something like this should work :

```
int manpowerBudget = committedHoursPerDay.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .mapToInt(o -> o.getKey().getHourlyWage() * o.getValue()) // or mapToDouble if you want double instead of int
        .sum();
```

Answer (score 1):

The existing answers assume that you don't need to create the `Map` first. In a situation where you do, probably because you'll use it elsewhere, here are some alternatives:

```
int manpowerBudget = employeeBudget .values().stream().reduce(0, Integer::sum);
```

**UPDATE:** If performance is important, I would suggest the above over @D. Lawrence's answer. There is no need to map.

Another option is:

```
int manpowerBudget = map.values().stream().collect(Collectors.summingInt(Integer::intValue));
```

But you may as well use your original method instead of the second one.